# Using Wire in a Child Lightning Web Component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, promises, parent-to-child, lightning-tabset

I'm trying to build a TabSet form where each child component is a different form. I would like to use `@wire` in the child components to grab the object needed for the form. However, I can only get it to work using promises on the apex method in the child component.

#### main question:

Do I need to utilize promises if I am calling an apex method in a child component?

Is it more efficient to call my apex methods in the parent component and pass the objects to each component?

#### <c-parent> HTML

```
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Two" title="2nd tab extended title">
            Two Content !
        </lightning-tab>
        <lightning-tab label="Item Three">
            Three Content !
        </lightning-tab>
            <lightning-tab label="Basic Profile Information">
               <c-basic-profile-information record-id={recordId}></c-basic-profile-information>
            </lightning-tab>
        </lightning-tabset>
```

#### <c-parent> JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import {NavigationMixin} from "lightning/navigation";

export default class UniversalIntakeForm extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    @api recordId = USER_ID; 
}
```

#### <c-Child> HTML

```
<template>
    <template if:true={contact} >
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" record-id={contact.data.Id}>
            <lightning-messages>
            </lightning-messages>
            <lightning-input-field field-name=FirstName>
            </lightning-input-field>
                <lightning-button
                    class="slds-m-top_small"
                    type="submit"
                    label="Update">
                </lightning-button>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    </template>
    
</template>
```

#### <c-Child> JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire} from 'lwc';
import getContactRecord from '@salesforce/apex/Communities.getContactRecord'

export default class BasicProfileInformation extends LightningElement {
    @api contact;
    @api recordId; 
    
    @wire (getContactRecord, {userId: '$recordId'})
    contact; 
    /* Commented out Promise */
    // connectedCallback(){
//     this.getContactRecord(this.recordId);
// }

// getContactRecord(userId){
//     getContactRecord({userId: userId
//     })
//     .then((result) => {
//         console.log(result);
//         this.contact = result; 
//     })
//     .catch((error) => {
//         console.log(error);
//     })
//     .finally(() =>{
//         console.log('FINALLY'); 
//     })
// }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@api contact;
...
@wire (getContactRecord, {userId: '$recordId'})
contact;
```

You defined the same variable twice, and this created a conflict. Remove the `@api contact;` and your code should work.

> Do I need to utilize promises if I am calling an apex method in a child component?

No.

> Is it more efficient to call my apex methods in the parent component and pass the objects to each component?

If your method is `@AuraEnabled` (as of version 43.0 or so), or `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` (any version), no, it is not *more* efficient (but it is *just as* efficient), as the system can just use the cache. If not using the cache, calling once from the parent and passing it to all children is more efficient.